# Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12780 \"(null)\"

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, avasset, avassetexportsession

When I try to export the asset with AVAssetExport I get the following error only on videos received through whatsapp probably.

I could not find a working solution. I've also tried implementing code to fix video duration, but I did not fix it.

Error is:

> Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12780 \"(null)\"

Here code

```
PHCachingImageManager().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset.phAsset!, options: nil, resultHandler: { (AVAssetRecivied, audioMix, info) in
                let AVAssetMy = AVAssetRecivied!.normalizingMediaDuration()
                let exportSession : AVAssetExportSession?
                if (AVAssetMy as? AVURLAsset) != nil {
                exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: (AVAssetMy as? AVURLAsset)!, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality)
                }
                else {
                exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: (AVAssetMy as? AVComposition)!, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality)
                }
                exportSession?.outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + NSUUID().uuidString + ".m4v")
                exportSession?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                exportSession?.audioMix = audioMix
                exportSession?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
                exportSession?.exportAsynchronously { () -> Void in
                    if exportSession?.status == .completed {
                    self.getFileSize(url: exportSession!.outputURL!)
                    if self.myMediaArray == nil {
                        self.myMediaArray = [["Video" : AVAsset(url: exportSession!.outputURL!)]]
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.collectionViewImage.reloadData()
                        }
                    } else {
                        self.myMediaArray?.append(["Video" : AVAsset(url: exportSession!.outputURL!)])
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.collectionViewImage.reloadData()
                        }
                    }}
                }
            })
```

Here is the method for adjusting the duration of the video

```
func normalizingMediaDuration() -> AVAsset? {
    let mixComposition : AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    var mutableCompositionVideoTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
    var mutableCompositionAudioTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
    let totalVideoCompositionInstruction : AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()

    guard let video = tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).first else {
        return nil
    }

    guard let audio = tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio).first else {
        return nil
    }

    mutableCompositionVideoTrack.append(mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    mutableCompositionAudioTrack.append(mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

    let duration = video.timeRange.duration.seconds > audio.timeRange.duration.seconds ? audio.timeRange.duration : video.timeRange.duration

    do{
        try mutableCompositionVideoTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,duration), of: video, at: kCMTimeZero)
        try mutableCompositionAudioTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, duration), of: audio, at: kCMTimeZero)
    }catch{
        return nil
    }

    totalVideoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,duration)

    return mixComposition
}
}
```

The file is:

1) Exportable
2) Presets and format are compatible
3) I tried to move the file to the document's before I export 4) I tried to change the file extension.

Comment: I just spend a tsi ( incident ) and i was reported to have a bug in the method that does not allow the export of some specific video. They welcome alternatives!

Answer (score 0):

It’s a bug.
Bug report : https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=34574848
Alternatives are welcome...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and got the same error code -12780.
The only thing that fixed it for me was:
sending to exportSession?.outputURL a NSURL variable and putting as URL
I have no idea why it worked and I hope you'll find it helpful as well.